# Python 3 ImportError: cannot import name 'Config' when importing boto3 after installing with pip3

Tags: install, homebrew, python

Currently trying to configure Python3 correctly with boto3 to utilize the AWS Dynamo Python SDK. I've used HomeBrew to install Python3 and then I've installed pip and pip3 for my python 2 and python 3 versions respectively.

I've also installed boto and boto3 for both Python2 and Python3.

```
workspace: python -c "import boto"
workspace: python -c "import boto3"
workspace: python3 -c "import boto"
workspace: python3 -c "import boto3"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from boto3.session import Session
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/boto3/session.py", line 18, in <module>
    from botocore.client import Config
ImportError: cannot import name 'Config'
```

But it's Python 3 that's giving me the problem as you can see above. Here's my full setup:

```
workspace: which python
/usr/bin/python
workspace: which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3

workspace: brew list --versions python3
python3 3.6.0_1

workspace: sudo pip install boto; sudo pip install boto3;
Requirement already satisfied: boto in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: futures<4.0.0,>=2.2.0; python_version == "2.6" or python_version == "2.7" in /    Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0-    >boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from     botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->    botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0->boto3)    

workspace: pip3 install boto; pip3 install boto3;
Requirement already satisfied: boto in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: boto3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: jmespath<1.0.0,>=0.7.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: s3transfer<0.2.0,>=0.1.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils>=0.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0->boto3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from python-dateutil<3.0.0,>=2.1->botocore<1.6.0,>=1.5.0->boto3)
```

The frustrating thing is that boto3 works totally fine on Python 2.7.10 which came with my macOS install. But I'd like to use Python 3 and can't seem to continue with it.

Answer (score 1):

It will work if you specifically install Python 3.5, not sure if they have updated it for 3.6 yet, but recently it was incompatible with it.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I removed all existing Homebrew versions of Python, and installed Python 3.5 using this tap: https://github.com/sashkab/homebrew-python. Same problem.

Comment: That installs 3.5.5. It may be that I was using an older 3.5 version I can't check anymore though. The official AWS page says it is fully supported to 3.4 https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/06/boto3-aws-sdk-for-python-version-3-is-now-generally-available/ but I would like to think that is out of date now. It definitely does work with some versions though so it may be a case of trial and error depending on what python release functionality you ideally want.